# Is it possible to convert a node's InnerXml to a new collection of nodes? (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file that I am trying to parse and load content from the file into a collection of custom classes.

I need to use an XMLnode's InnerXml and extract (or create) an additional collection of XMLNodes from that string.

I've googled as well as I can to find a solution, but nothing quite fits what I'm after. Is it possible to do that?

thanks

Comment: You can create a new XmlElement and set the innerxml to your xml and they will become node collection under that element.

Comment: @MatJ would it be possible to explain a little further? I'm not exactly sure how I would cast my innerxml to a new XMLElement. thanks

Comment: You need not cast it, you just create a new object of [XmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=netframework-4.8) class, it has a property called [InnerXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.innerxml?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlElement_InnerXml), which you can set a string to. Then you can get the node collection from its [ChildNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_ChildNodes) collection.

Comment: Yes.  Easiest with Xml Linq.  Need to see sample of xml file.

Comment: @MatJ Thank you. That's the pointer I needed. I've tried to find the button to indicate you gave the correct solution but I'm not seeing one. But anyway, yes, that seemed to do the trick. Thanks

Comment: @CanuckPlay, Glad to help, dont worry about that button, for that to be visible I have to write a full fledged answer below and I'm lazy to do that now at this 2am in the morning.